# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. while adding firebase authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Have been suffering with this error the whole day.

**Please don't mark this question as a duplicate.I have gone through many similar questions and none of the answers worked for me.**

Full error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'. 
> java.io.IOException: Can't write [E:\Educational\Career\Android\Projects
\FirebaseTutorial\app\build\intermediates\multi-dex\debug\componentClasses.jar] 
(Can't read [C:\Users\Abhi\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-
27.1.0.aar\167562b027fa4c1af2f69bce0de3dd43\jars\classes.jar(;;;;;;**.class)] 
(Duplicate zip entry [classes.jar:android/support/design/widget/CoordinatorLayout
$Behavior.class]))
```

**Things I have already tried :**

1. Clean and Rebuild
2. Invalidate Caches and Restart
3. Deleted .gradle in my project folder and resynced the project.
4. Deleted whole .gradle of android studio (In Users/Username/.gradle) *almost 2.5Gb of data* and tried syncing again.
5. Added :

   `android {`

   `defaultConfig {`

   `multiDexEnabled true`

   `}}`

to gradle file:

**My full gradle files :**

**app :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.appz.abhi.firebasetutorial"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}




apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**Top level gradle :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**This error occurred after adding firebase auth.**

P.S : Removing firebase auth dependencies and rebuilding the project doesn't show any error. i.e Removing

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2'
```

removes the error, but i want firebase Auth in my project.

Comment: Have you tried adding `implementation 'com.android.support.multidex:1.0.2'`?

Comment: @AlejandroBertinelli Thanks for answering. The accepted answer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported Support library for `firebase-ui-auth:3.2.2` is 27.0.2 not 27.1.0

So change:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
```

To

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
```

[FirebaseUi-Android releases](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases)

Comment: So Firebase UI doesn't support latest support library !!! Spent a hell lot of time in this error :-( and also had to delete all my libraries in .gradle folder.  (have to redownload them).   Thanks a lot for the answer . :-)

Comment: @Abhi wait for it... Users will blame you because Auth UI won't let them go back from the sign in screen...

Comment: @AlejandroBertinelli Sorry I can't understand what you told.

Comment: @JagarYousef you didn't understand anything 

Answer (score 0):

As @Jagar explains in his answer, FirebaseUI 3.2.2 has [transitive dependencies](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/releases) on Support Library 27.0.2.  If you want to build with a different version of the Support Libraries, such as 27.1.0, you must follow the [instructions described in the documentation](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#upgrading-dependencies) to add the appropriate libraries in your dependencies.  In your case, for FirebaseUI Auth, these are:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
```